# iPhone - UIToolbar disappears in previous view on popping

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitoolbar

I am using a navbar and toolbar in my application. One of the screens uses transparent toolbar and navbar which show when the user taps the screen. Everything works great except when I do a popViewController from this view controller.

The toolbar in my previous vc is no longer visible (I can see it if only for a second when the vc is popped and then it disappears)

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The tabbar is probably added to the view controlled by your subview controller so when the viewController is popped, it takes the toolbar with it.

You should add the toolbar to your window if you want it to stay around whilst the navbar changes views.

Comment: Thanks. Was an autoresizing issue. Just changed the options in IB